# Select columns from two different table with different fields in one query Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have the table `tbl_Discount` with these columns:

- d_ID
- Discount

And the table `tbl_Tarrif` with these columns:

- p_ID
- Price

I want to select `Discount` and `Price` in a single query and it's easy in SQL Server using a stored procedure but, in **Access** I don't know how to do it.

I tried this:

```
SELECT Discount
  FROM tbl_Discount
 WHERE (d_ID = ?)
 UNION
SELECT Price
  FROM tbl_Tariff
 WHERE (p_ID = ?)
```

But it returns two rows with one column each:

```
Discount
0
75000
```

And I want two columns (discount, price) on a single row, like this:

```
Discount Price
0        75000
```

Comment: add Access tag in answer, please

Comment: is d_ID a foreign key from tbl_Tariff in tbl_Discount ?

Comment: @Andrew Spartan I tried to add it but it doesn't allow me to add it.

Comment: @Homayoun no this two table haden't any realation with each other

Comment: You say it is easy to do in SQL Server as a sproc. Why not post that stored procedure here so we are sure what you are trying to translate to Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT Discount , Price
FROM tbl_Discount, tbl_Tariff
WHERE d_ID = ? AND p_ID = ?
```